# How to center a div with BlueprintCSS?

Tags: blueprint-css

So I have div within the container class. How do I center the div, so that it properly adds empty space equally to both sides, depending on the width of the div?

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    ... other stuff ...
    <div>center me</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
<div class="span-6 last prepend-9 append-9">contents</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you know the width of the page in span units because you define them when you build your blueprint-css file... so you could do something like this... "span-x" is the width of the segment or page in span units... "left" floats left, and "right" floats right... the two cancel and center the div.

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    ... other stuff ...
    <div class="span-x right left last">center me</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Blueprint has a "centered" style you can use:

```
<div class="span-10 centered">...</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Old question, I know but you could set the `margin-left` and `margin-right` of that `div` to `auto`. I believe that would do it.